# Multithreaded data structure : concurrent stack

Tags: c, concurrency, data-structures

I'm looking for a C implementation of a concurrent stack (like Cilk THE protocol) that would allow the main thread to push and pop (the pop operation would be at the begining of the stack for example) and a distant thread to pop (this pop operation would be at the end of the stack) with every precaution that has to be taken.

If no code, any implementation advice would be appreciated.

Thx!

Comment: If you want to push at the beginning and pop at the end then it is no stack but a queue.

Comment: Did you want the consumer ('distant thread') to block when it reads and there's nothing in there yet? (blocking queue)

Comment: Also, what environment? POSIX? Win32?

Comment: yes sorry about that, ideally a queue or a deque would be great, wait free would be perfect.
POSIX environnement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NOBLE](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/noble/) Library seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a regular stack and wrap the push and pop functions with mutexes.

In psuedo-C:

```
void push(void *data)
{
    acquire_lock(mutex);
    stack_push(data)
    release_lock(mutex);
}
```

Add error checking and salt to taste.

Comment: In fact I'm looking for wait free or lock free implementation for HPC application so the mutex solution is to avoid (that's why I pointed the Cilk protocol)